# How to output variable in nginx log for debugging

Tags: nginx

I am testing nginx and want to output variables to the log files. How can I do that and which log file will it go (access or error).

Answer (score 240, accepted):

You can send nginx variable values via headers. Handy for development.

```
add_header X-uri "$uri";
```

and you'll see in your browser's response headers:

```
X-uri:/index.php
```

I sometimes do this during local development.

It's also handy for telling you if a subsection is getting executed or not. Just sprinkle it inside your clauses to see if they're getting used.

```
location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt)$ {
    add_header X-debug-message "A static file was served" always;
    ...
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    add_header X-debug-message "A php file was used" always;
    ...
}
```

So visiting a url like http://www.example.com/index.php will trigger the latter header while visiting http://www.example.com/img/my-ducky.png will trigger the former header.

Comment: Note that `add_header` will work [on successful requests only](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpHeadersModule#add_header). Documentation states that it can only be applied to responses with codes 200, 204, 301, 302 or 304. Therefore, it can't be used to debug HTTP errors.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith : As marat noted in [this answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/418709/nginx-add-header-for-a-50-page/647552#647552). As of [version 1.7.5](http://nginx.org/en/CHANGES), nginx added an ["always" parameter](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html) to ```add_header``` which will return the header, no matter what the response code. So for example, ```add_header X-debug-message "A php file was used" always;```, should work even for 500 error code.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. The guy wants to log to **log file** not to the client.

Comment: Doesn't work.  I am doing proxy_pass.  The header is NOT present in the response.

Comment: answering @Avamander you are right! OP asked a simple question how to render custom logging... can be done using Nginx directive: set $append_log 'custom_field=$custom_data';

Comment: also one trick we do is to nest $append_log statements, using a default set of custom logging in the Server{} block level, example above, then we add any granular detail in the Location{} block level as follows: set $append_log '$append_log v_loc=$my_loc_name';

Answer (score 70):

You can return a simple string as HTTP response:

```
location / {
    add_header Content-Type text/plain;
    return 200 $document_root;
}
```

Or use interpolation for watching multiple variables at the same time:

```
location / {
    add_header Content-Type text/plain;
    return 200 "document_root: $document_root, request_uri: $request_uri";
}
```

Comment: What if you want to return two variables values?

Comment: Going to the location immediately opens the Save As dialog of my browser (tested on Opera, Chromium). No response whatsoever.

Comment: @BringBackCommodore64 Adding a text/html Content-Type header may help.

Comment: Using [Postman](https://getpostman.com), this works without any additional headers. Thanks!

Comment: I want to return multiple variables and solved it like this;

`return 200 "xforwardedfor:$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for--remote_addr:$remote_addr--scheme:$scheme--host:$host";
`

Answer (score 24):

You can set a custom access log format using the [`log_format`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLogModule#log_format) directive which logs the variables you're interested in.

Comment: thanks, and I guess there is no easier way to output one variable by itself?

Comment: @lulalala Not that I know of.

Comment: It is possible set the log level in the directive `error_log` to `debug` so you can see the value of the variables and that block that are execute. Example `error_log file.log debug`

Comment: notice thar empty variables are shown as `-` in the log, but are really empty in the nginx code, you should not check for `-` at any time. This sometimes confuse users.

Answer (score 8):

Another option is to include [the echo module](https://github.com/agentzh/echo-nginx-module) when you build nginx, or install [OpenResty](http://openresty.org/) which is nginx bundled with a bunch of extensions (like echo.)

Then you can simply sprinkle your configuration with statements like:

```
echo "args: $args"
```

Comment: When I try this it echos out to a plain text file on the server interrupting the output of the actual page.

Comment: There is an `echo_log` directive in development.

Comment: @Gajus Three years later now, and I googled for this, but can't find anything about `echo_log`.  Do you know if it ever got out of development?

Answer (score 5):

none of these answer the question as asked (log)

However, @Victor Aguilar - has a comment on this answer, that should be an answer!  It says how to log variables, and it works.  Thanks!

https://serverfault.com/a/404628/400075

i.e. in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

`error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;`

results in the following type of logging:

```
2021/03/06 15:14:48 [debug] 2550#2550: *1 fastcgi param: "SCRIPT_FILENAME: /usr/lib/cgit/cgit.cgi/something.git/cgit.cgi"
2021/03/06 15:14:48 [debug] 2550#2550: *1 http script copy: "QUERY_STRING"
2021/03/06 15:14:48 [debug] 2550#2550: *1 fastcgi param: "QUERY_STRING: "
2021/03/06 15:14:48 [debug] 2550#2550: *1 http script copy: "REQUEST_METHOD"
2021/03/06 15:14:48 [debug] 2550#2550: *1 http script var: "GET"
2021/03/06 15:14:48 [debug] 2550#2550: *1 fastcgi param: "REQUEST_METHOD: GET"
2021/03/06 15:14:48 [debug] 2550#2550: *1 http script copy: "CONTENT_TYPE"
2021/03/06 15:14:48 [debug] 2550#2550: *1 fastcgi param: "CONTENT_TYPE: "
2021/03/06 15:14:48 [debug] 2550#2550: *1 http script copy: "CONTENT_LENGTH"
2021/03/06 15:14:48 [debug] 2550#2550: *1 fastcgi param: "CONTENT_LENGTH: "
2021/03/06 15:14:48 [debug] 2550#2550: *1 http script copy: "SCRIPT_NAME"
2021/03/06 15:14:48 [debug] 2550#2550: *1 http script var: "/cgit/cgit.cgi/something.git/cgit.cgi"
2021/03/06 15:14:48 [debug] 2550#2550: *1 fastcgi param: "SCRIPT_NAME: /cgit/cgit.cgi/something.git/cgit.
cgi"
2021/03/06 15:14:48 [debug] 2550#2550: *1 http script copy: "REQUEST_URI"
2021/03/06 15:14:48 [debug] 2550#2550: *1 http script var: "/cgit/cgit.cgi/something.git/"
2021/03/06 15:14:48 [debug] 2550#2550: *1 fastcgi param: "REQUEST_URI: /cgit/cgit.cgi/something.git/"
2021/03/06 15:14:48 [debug] 2550#2550: *1 http script copy: "DOCUMENT_URI"
2021/03/06 15:14:48 [debug] 2550#2550: *1 http script var: "/cgit/cgit.cgi/something.git/"
2021/03/06 15:14:48 [debug] 2550#2550: *1 fastcgi param: "DOCUMENT_URI: /cgit/cgit.cgi/something.git/"
2021/03/06 15:14:48 [debug] 2550#2550: *1 http script copy: "DOCUMENT_ROOT"
2021/03/06 15:14:48 [debug] 2550#2550: *1 http script var: "/usr/lib"
2021/03/06 15:14:48 [debug] 2550#2550: *1 fastcgi param: "DOCUMENT_ROOT: /usr/lib"
2021/03/06 15:14:48 [debug] 2550#2550: *1 http script copy: "SERVER_PROTOCOL"
2021/03/06 15:14:48 [debug] 2550#2550: *....
```

Comment: not all nginx packages ar buit with --with-debug flag so debug directive is useless in error_log  if nginx built with --with-debug  (as I see most of nginxes are built without)