# Nginx add_header for a 50* page

Tags: nginx, http-headers, 500-error

I'm currently trying to get nginx to add a header to the response when it is sending some kind of 50* error. I already have an add_header directive on the http block, and that gets respected for all requests except it seems errors. I also tried the following in one of my vhosts:

```
location /mediocregopheristhecoolest {
    add_header X-Test "blahblahblah";
    return 502;                                                                                                    
}
```

Going to that page gives me a 502, but no header. Is this simply something nginx doesn't do, or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Could you post the output of $ curl -I <url>//mediocregopheristhecoolest

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[The documentation](http://nginx.org/r/add_header) states that add_header "Adds the specified field to a response header provided that the response code equals 200, 204, 206, 301, 302, 303, 304, or 307. A value can contain variables."  So it doesn't work with a 502.

I forgot to add that you can use the third party [headers more](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersMoreModule) module to add headers to other codes.  You'll probably have to recompile to add it, though.

Comment: See comment of marat: the new nginx version supports setting the header irrespective of response code

Answer (score 67):

Since Nginx 1.7.5 you can use `always` to add a header irrespective of the response code:

```
add_header X-Test "blahblahblah" always;
```

Comment: Frustratingly, the version in Debian's repos is currently outdated (1.6.x), but nginx [maintains their own repository](http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html) with the latest stable build (1.8.x right now).

Comment: If you want to upgrade an already working debian system, debian backports is safer... https://packages.debian.org/jessie-backports/httpd/nginx The upstream package use different package organisation (may cause some downtime instead of the smooth nginx upgrade mechanism). And its postrm script removes the logs. And a couple of other small differences...

Comment: This doesn't work for me. If I make nginx reply with 502 because all the upstream servers are unavailable due to fails, it doesn't send the header. I even tried setting on the http block

Comment: nevermind, it seems somehow wget was not displaying the header with -S, but with curl i could see it wtf