# 'File not found' exact path in nginx and php-fpm

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, http-status-code-404

Sometimes when configuring nginx and php-fpm I get message "File not found."
I know this is beacause of wrong parameter SCRIPT_FILENAME, e.g.:

```
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  /some/path$fastcgi_script_name;
```

I wonder is there a way to get exact full path of file which is cannot be found by php-fpm?

My php5-fpm.log has nothing, but:

```
[06-Jan-2014 11:14:33] NOTICE: configuration file /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf test is successful
[06-Jan-2014 11:27:01] NOTICE: configuration file /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf test is successful
```

I've tried to change `log_level` option in php-fpm.conf to `error` and `debug`, but result remains the same

P.S.
This line:

```
add_header X-My-Header /some/path$fastcgi_script_name;
```

doesn't do the trick, because `add_header` only works with successful responses, as I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14501047/how-to-add-a-response-header-on-nginx-when-using-proxy-pass)

There is the [nginx module](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpHeadersMoreModule), that allows to set header even with fail responses,
but I think it should be an easier way to get file path.

Thank you.

Comment: Are your scripts in the same location as the root directory set in the Nginx configuration?

Comment: @Jason Ilicic it my case they are. But i'm looking for all-purpose decision.

Comment: I'm unsure exactly how to get the path output. I use "fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;" which seems to work fine for me. I would also ensure that the permissions are appropriate for the files to be accessed by the PHP-FPM workers.

Comment: Also, you may be able to set a custom log_format, as mentioned here: http://serverfault.com/questions/404626/how-to-output-variable-in-nginx-log-for-debugging

Comment: my php5-fpm.log has rw------- permissions and is owned by root. and php-fpm workers are running by www-data. I've changed permissions to rw-rw-rw- but it is still not logging

Comment: @JasonIlicic `log_format` works. By this time this is the best decision. Thank you!

Comment: No problems, would be good if you could post your solution as an answer for future reference :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution would be the logging needed variables by nginx using `log_format`.

In the simplest case it may look like this (paste this code into `http` context):

```
log_format mylog '$fastcgi_script_name';
access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  mylog;
```

Then you can see results in access log file (in my case `/var/log/nginx/access.log`).

Another solution is to compile nginx with [HttpHeadersMoreModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpHeadersMoreModule).
This module allows you to manipulate http headers with much more flexibility than with nginx default `add_header` directive.
So to view `$fastcgi_script_name` value you can write:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    more_set_headers    "x-debug-header: $fastcgi_script_name";
    fastcgi_pass        127.0.0.1:9000;
    ...
}
```

Then you can see headers in Google Chrome DevTools in the Network tab (or similar tools in other browsers).

P.S. with HttpHeadersMoreModule you can also rewrite a `Server` header, if you need of course:

```
more_set_headers    "Server: my_server";
```

Good luck!