# The `location` directive has no effect when it contains a variable

Tags: nginx

### What I want

For my `/admin` location, whitelist several trusted IP addresses, and block everyone else.

### What I have

```
http {
    map $remote_addr $admin_block_path {
        default "/admin";
        1.1.1.1 "/not-admin";
        8.8.8.8 "/not-admin";
    }

    # …

    server {
        add_header X-Test-Admin "$admin_block_path";
        location $admin_block_path {
            return 403;
        }
    }

}
```

The idea is to [use `map`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15416957/using-variables-in-nginx-location-rules/61513351#61513351) do conditionally determine a path to block from a visitor IP address. Store it in a variable, and use that variable in `location`. If the request comes from a non-trusted IP, the variable will contain `/admin`, and therefore the location will block `/admin`.

### What is the problem

The `location` does not block access to `/admin`.

- I can confirm [using `add_header`](https://serverfault.com/questions/404626/how-to-output-variable-in-nginx-log-for-debugging/580739#580739) that the variable is set based on the IP address correctly. When visiting from a non-trusted IP I do get `/admin`, and respectively `/non-admin` when visiting from a trusted IP.
- If I replace `location $admin_block_path` with hardcoded `location /admin`, the request does get blocked
- Tried playing with double quotes, no effect
- Tried taking the slash outside of the variable, no effect

### Note

Unfortunately, I can't simply hardcode `allow`/`deny` into some `/admin` location because that would overwrite PHP pass configuration I have elsewhere in the config. Because of this, I need to have a dedicated `/admin` location only if I know I'll reject the request anyway, and no PHP will be needed.

Nginx version: 1.20.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the locations in the nginx config are compiled at the startup. You can't use variables for the `location` directive parameter (as well as you can't use variables inside the regex patterns or with some other directives). Moreover when nginx directive documentation doesn't explicitly states that you can use variables for the parameter of some directive, generally it means you cannot. You should use some other technique to achieve what you want to. One of solutions can be the following:

```
map $remote_addr $admin_block_path {
    1.1.1.1 "";
    8.8.8.8 "";
    default 1;
}

server {
    if ($admin_block_path) {
        rewrite ^/admin /blocked;
    }
    location = /blocked {
        internal;
        return 403;
    }
    ...
}
```

An exact match location have a greater priority over the regex one so it should not break your PHP handler configuration. Making that location internal you can assured it won't be accessible directly (only via rewrite rule).